# rowspan en table html no funciona

Tags: html, html5

Tengo una tabla que quiero que las primeras columnas sean una sola con la primera fila, pero no me funciona el rowspan:

```html
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 97px;"></th>
            <th style="width: 32px;"></th>
            <th style="width: 57px;"></th>
            <th style="width: 56px;"></th>
            <th style="width: 52px;"></th>
            <th style="width: 59px;"></th>
            <th style="width: 52px;"></th>
            <th style="width: 39px;"></th>
            <th colspan="5" style="width: 379px;">
                <h3>MINSAL</h3>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="2" style="width: 97px;">Departamento</th>
            <th rowspan="2" style="width: 32px;">ISSS</th>
            <th rowspan="2" style="width: 57px;">Sanidad Militar</th>
            <th rowspan="2" style="width: 56px;">Alcaldia</th>
            <th style="width: 52px;">Centro Escolar</th>
            <th style="width: 59px;">COLVOL</th>
            <th style="width: 52px;">Lideres</th>
            <th style="width: 39px;">Otros</th>
            <th style="width: 61px;">Personal<br /> M&eacute;dico</th>
            <th style="width: 74px;">Personal<br /> Enfermeria</th>
            <th style="width: 82px;">odontologo</th>
            <th style="width: 101px;">Personal <br /> Administrativo</th>
            <th style="width: 61px;">Otro <br />Personal</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes probar esto. Debería funcionar. El ROWSPAN se aplica a la fila de más arriba de la tabla para que funcione.

```
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th rowspan="2"  style="width: 97px;">Departamento</th>
        <th rowspan="2" style="width: 32px;">ISSS</th>
        <th rowspan="2" style="width: 57px;">Sanidad Militar</th>
        <th rowspan="2" style="width: 56px;">Alcaldia</th>
        <th colspan="5" style="width: 379px;">
            <h3>MINSAL</h3>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th style="width: 52px;">Centro Escolar</th>
        <th style="width: 59px;">COLVOL</th>
        <th style="width: 52px;">Lideres</th>
        <th style="width: 39px;">Otros</th>
        <th style="width: 61px;">Personal<br /> M&eacute;dico</th>
        <th style="width: 74px;">Personal<br /> Enfermeria</th>
        <th style="width: 82px;">odontologo</th>
        <th style="width: 101px;">Personal <br /> Administrativo</th>
        <th style="width: 61px;">Otro <br />Personal</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Acá hay un [JsFiddle con el código](http://jsfiddle.net/bqpafo5s/2/#&togetherjs=FU3GlLKKNr) para hacer más pruebas.